# ModuleNotFoundError for 'undetected_chromedriver' with PyInstaller and py2exe in Python 3.11.7

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

I am trying to convert a Python script into a standalone executable using both `PyInstaller` and `py2exe`. However, I'm encountering a `ModuleNotFoundError` for the `undetected_chromedriver` module in both cases. My `Python` version is `3.11.7`. The script runs perfectly in my development environment, but when packaged with `PyInstaller` or `py2exe`, it fails to recognize the `undetected_chromedriver` module.

Attempt with `PyInstaller`:
I used the following command with `PyInstaller`:

```
pyinstaller --clean --onefile --debug=all .\main.py
```

The build completes successfully, but running the executable yields:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'
```

Attempt with `py2exe`:
For `py2exe`, I used this setup script (`setup.py`):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['main.py'])
```

And ran the build using:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Again, the build is successful, but the executable produces the same `ModuleNotFoundError`.

> Details:

- Python Version: 3.11.7
- OS: Windows 10
- The script runs without issues in `PyCharm` and via the `Windows command line`.
- `undetected_chromedriver` is installed and working in the development
  environment.

I have tried using the `--hidden-import` flag with `PyInstaller` and specifying includes in the `setup.py` for `py2exe` without success.

1. How can I resolve the `ModuleNotFoundError` for
   `undetected_chromedriver` when using `PyInstaller` and `py2exe`?
2. Are there specific considerations for `undetected_chromedriver` with
   these tools that I might be missing?